# Simple PHP class

Tags: php

I am learning `php` and created the below class, but I can't seem to figure out why it giving me the below errors which says:

`144`

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for setters::set_a(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\accessmod2.php on line 19 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\accessmod2.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\accessmod2.php on line 11

```
<?php

class setters{
    private $a = 144;
    public function get_a(){
        return $this->a;
    }

    public function set_a($value){

        $this->a = $value;
    }
}

$example = new setters();

echo $example->get_a()."<br />";
$example->set_a(15)."<br />";
echo $example->set_a()."<br />";

?>
```

Comment: `set_a` require a parameter, `echo $example->set_a()` doesn't have one.

Comment: `function set_a($value)` <-- it _requires_ you to provide a value when calling the method. `$example->set_a()`<-- no arg provided.

Comment: You probably meant to call `$example->get_a()` on that last line to see the effect of the previous line.

Comment: @S.I. Why this edit? It's not the original code ...

Comment: @Berserk I have no idea what is happening here.. I will edit it with original code. I really don't know..

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a parameter for the `set()` function. But in your case, I think you just want to see if the `set()` function have work. So use the `get()` function.

So change to this :

```
echo $example->get_a()."<br />";
$example->set_a(15)."<br />";
echo $example->get_a()."<br />";
```

And the result is :

```
144
15
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your last line:

```
echo $example->set_a()."<br />";
```

`set_a()` requires a parameter but it is empty. If you change it like this, it will work:

```
echo $example->set_a('someparameterhere')."<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second call to `->set_a` requires a parameter :

```
<?php

class setters{
    private $a = 144;
    public function get_a(){
        return $this->a;
    }

    public function set_a($value){

        $this->a = $value;
    }
}

$example = new setters();

echo $example->get_a()."<br />";
$example->set_a(15)."<br />";
$example->set_a(23)."<br />"; // ◄■■■ PARAMETER FOR "SET_A".

?>
```

You can also use an "optional" parameter :

```
<?php

class setters{
    private $a = 144;
    public function get_a(){
        return $this->a;
    }

    public function set_a( $value = -1 ){ // ◄■■■ OPTIONAL PARAMETER.

        $this->a = $value;
    }
}

$example = new setters();

echo $example->get_a()."<br />";
$example->set_a()."<br />"; // ◄■■■ OPTIONAL PARAMETER ($a = -1).
echo $example->get_a()."<br />"; // ◄■■■ NEW VALUE = -1.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `set_a` *twice*.

After set, you need call `get_a` to show the value.

```
echo $example->get_a()."<br />";
$example->set_a(15)."<br />";
echo $example->get_a()."<br />";
```